# android: Sony Xperia: custom view with scroll bars

Tags: android, sony

I am creating a custom view to represent some kind of a content. I want this content to be scrollable (vertically) and I want standard scroll bars to be visible during the scroll. In order to do this I've included the following code to the cinstructor of my custom view:

```
setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.View);
initializeScrollbars(a);
a.recycle();
```

Now, this `R.stylable.View` is as follows:

```
<declare-styleable name="View">
    <attr name="android:fadeScrollbars"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarFadeDuration"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarSize"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarStyle"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbars"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

This code works properly on each and every Android device. Except for the **Sony Xperia Z** which gives me the `NumberFormatException` each time it comes across `initializeScrollbars(a)` :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "25.0dip"
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:122)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:254)
at android.view.View.initializeScrollbars(View.java:4172)
at TheCustomViewIAmTryingToCreate.<init>(MyCustomView.java:164)
... 36 more
```

I can see that it interprets some XML-defined value incorrectly but I can not get which one exactly. This line:

```
at android.view.View.initializeScrollbars(View.java:4172)
```

points me to the source of `View` class which I reviewed in order to find the reason. The problem is that `initializeScrollbars` method (official Android source) has nothing to do with line **4172**. Obviuosly Sony (in some way) modified Android on their devices which now makes my code crash.

Does anyone know what causes such a problem or where can I find sources for Android installed on **Xperia Z1 (C6903)** to look at the reason of this problem?

**Edit:** This also happens on **Xperia Tablet Z (SGP321)** and **Xperia ZL (C6503)**

Comment: where you used 25.0dip ?

Comment: It is defined somewhere deep inside standard `themes.xml` file of Android version used on Sony devices. I am unable to find out where exactly since I have no access to this particular data.

Comment: can you change it to  25 from 25.0 ?

Comment: Have you even read my question?

Comment: have u tried : can you change it to 25 from 25.0 ?

Comment: **No, I can not!** This value is defined somewhere deep inside Android (Sony version) and I do not know what attribute of the scrollbar this value is defined for (Thanks for your effort but it does not lead anywhere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still **do not know what caused this crash** but I have managed to fix it. I ended up extending `R.stylable.View` with some more attributes:

```
<declare-styleable name="View">
    <attr name="android:background"/>
    <attr name="android:clickable"/>
    <attr name="android:contentDescription"/>
    <attr name="android:drawingCacheQuality"/>
    <attr name="android:duplicateParentState"/>
    <attr name="android:fadeScrollbars"/>
    <attr name="android:fadingEdge"/>
    <attr name="android:fadingEdgeLength"/>
    <attr name="android:fitsSystemWindows"/>
    <attr name="android:focusable"/>
    <attr name="android:focusableInTouchMode"/>
    <attr name="android:hapticFeedbackEnabled"/>
    <attr name="android:id"/>
    <attr name="android:isScrollContainer"/>
    <attr name="android:keepScreenOn"/>
    <attr name="android:longClickable"/>
    <attr name="android:minHeight"/>
    <attr name="android:minWidth"/>
    <attr name="android:nextFocusDown"/>
    <attr name="android:nextFocusLeft"/>
    <attr name="android:nextFocusRight"/>
    <attr name="android:nextFocusUp"/>
    <attr name="android:onClick"/>
    <attr name="android:padding"/>
    <attr name="android:paddingBottom"/>
    <attr name="android:paddingLeft"/>
    <attr name="android:paddingRight"/>
    <attr name="android:paddingTop"/>
    <attr name="android:saveEnabled"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollX"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollY"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarFadeDuration"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarSize"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarStyle"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical"/>
    <attr name="android:scrollbars"/>
    <attr name="android:soundEffectsEnabled"/>
    <attr name="android:tag"/>
    <attr name="android:visibility"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Maybe this is too much but my application no longer crashes after that.

Though it is not necessary anymore, still if anyone has any idea on where I went wrong please do not leave me unenlightened.